# How to add a document to collection using ID in Firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a to-do list app, and I'm trying to allow the user to create their own custom category; this part has been done. When the user clicks on the category, they get taken to a page where they can add their own todos. I want to use the ID of the created custom category and allow the user to create a todo using the category's ID. When I type in the input field and submit, nothing happens, and it is not added to the collection.

Images

[Custom category](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYz0R.png)

[custom todo page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bh7mX.png)

Code

```
 import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  collection,
  getDocs,
  addDoc,
  query,
  where,
  doc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
 import { db } from "../../firebase";

function CustomCategory() {
      const [customTodo, setCustomTodo] = useState("");
      const [customTodos, setCustomTodos] = useState([]);
 
  const { id } = useParams();

  const createCustomTodo = async () => {
 
    const todo = {
      title: customTodo || null,
    };
            console.log("add custom todo");


        try {
          const docRef = await addDoc(
            collection(db, "customCategories").where("id", "==", id),
            {
              ...todo,
            }
          );

          window.location.reload();

          console.log(docRef);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error("Error adding document: ", e);
        }
        setCustomTodo(todo)

    console.log("print")
   };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="container">
        <h2>The id is: {id}</h2>
        <div className="d-flex gap-3">
          <input
            className="w-75 align-items-center
            "
            type="text"
            placeholder="Please enter your todo"
          />
          <button className="btn btn-primary" onClick={createCustomTodo}>
            Submit
          </button>
          {customTodos.map((todo, i) => (
            <Card>
              <CardBody>
                <div
                  className="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
                  direction="vertical"
                  gap={3}
                >
                  <div>
                    <i className="fas fa-ticket"></i>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </CardBody>
              <CardBody>
                <div className="d-flex  justify-content-between gap-3 bg">
                  <div></div>
                  <div>
                    <p key={i} className="w-80 align-self-center">
                      <h1>hghghjjghj</h1>
                    </p>
                  </div>
                  <div>
                    <p className="no-wrap ">{todo}</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </CardBody>
            </Card>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default CustomCategory;
```

I tried reading the documentation and seeing how i can use the where statement but it is not adding to firestore. I appricate any help so i can see what i'm doing wrong.

Comment: You can't use a where clause like you're trying to do now.  And addDoc only adds a document to a collection with a random ID.  You haven't explained very well what the final result is that you're trying to accomplish.  Maybe you are trying to use [setDoc as illustrated in the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document)?  Please edit the question to be more clear what you're trying to do and what the specific error message is.

Comment: I have added more information of what I'm trying to do. I have added pictures of the custom category and the custom todo. So when the user clicks on the custom category they have made, it goes to custom todo page.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a document with an ID that you specify, don't use `addDoc`. Instead use `setDoc` as shown in the documentation on [setting a document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document).

```
const docRef = await setDoc(
  doc(db, "customCategories", id),
  todo
);
```